# Firebase - Needing to find document id using 'where'

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to find the document label (name/id?) of a document I acquire with the .where(...)

What am I doing wrong?

```
   // updates dev team in the db
function updateDevTeam(devToUpdate, update) { // devToUpdate = id of dev, fieldToUpdate = goal, name, or team_id, update = value
    var devToUpdateDocument = fb.db.collection('dev').where('id', '==', devToUpdate) //how do I set this to the document id(/name/path?)
    fb.db.collection('dev').doc(devToUpdateDocument).update({ team_id: update })
}
```

Comment: read this carefully: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to update all documents that would result from a query.  Firestore doesn't have an "update where" function like SQL.

It's not possible to update a document if you don't have a reference to that document.  To update all the documents that match a query, you have to:

1. Actually perform the query
2. Iterate all the documents in the result

   - Get a reference to the document
   - Update it individually

```
// Your query object
const query = fb.db.collection('dev').where('id', '==', devToUpdate)
// now actually perform the query to get a QuerySnapshot
query.get().then(qsnapshot => {
    // then iterate each document in the result set to update it
    qsnapshot.docs.forEach(dsnapshot => {
        // get a reference to the document in the DocumentSnapshot
        const ref = dsnapshot.ref
        // and update it
        ref.update(...)
    })
})
```